# Android Plotting 2D Graph

Tags: java, android, user-interface, graphics, graph

I am developing one app and I want to show 2D (x-y coordinates) graph, in my activity. I have looked on internet there are lots of third party libs capable of drawing graphs. But I am looking for android built in lib or widget, which will draw graph. Also is it possible with Canvas ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link contains a class plot2d.java 
which was written by importing Canvas

http://www.ankitsrivastava.net/2012/03/a-simple-2d-plot-class-for-android/

When you download the file the class is found in
GraphButton\GraphButton\src\com\android\graphbutton

The file should give you a clear way of implementing the 2D chart.